# Coreml, Failure verifying inputs. Image is not valid

Tags: ios, swift, neural-network, coreml, turi

Tried to follow https://www.appcoda.com/core-ml-model-with-python/
To build pictures recognition I use Core ML(Turi Create) + Python + Swift(iOS).

Tried to upload the same image that I've used to train for ".mlmodel" file.
Didn't help. Tried to load picture 100x100 size. The same error. What else can I try?

Output:

> 2018-04-17 20:54:19.076605+0200 [2516:1111075] [MC] System group
>   container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is
>   /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>
> 2018-04-17 20:54:19.077580+0200 [2516:1111075] [MC] Reading from
>   public effective user settings.
>
> 2018-04-17 20:54:54.795691+0200 [2516:1111075] [coreml] Error
>   Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=1 "Input image feature image does not
>   match model description" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Input image
>   feature image does not match model description,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x1c024cf90 {Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=1
>   "Image is not valid width 227, instead is 224"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Image is not valid width 227, instead
>   is 224}}}
>
> 2018-04-17 20:54:54.795728+0200 [2516:1111075] [coreml] Failure
>   verifying inputs.

Due to request from comments:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        previewImg.image = image

        if let buffer = image.buffer(with: CGSize(width: 224, height: 224)) {

            guard let prediction = try? mlModel.prediction(image: buffer) else {
                fatalError("Unexpected runtime error")
            }

            descriptionLbl.text = prediction.foodType
            print(prediction.foodTypeProbability)
        } else {
            print("failed buffer")
        }
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Post your code, particularly for `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])`

Comment: Tried to load standart trained model from tutorial ... it works. The weight if 95mb. My - 5mb. But I've found more images + better resolutions. Didn't help :( The same issue ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message literally says what the cause of the error is:

> 2018-04-17 20:54:54.795691+0200 [2516:1111075] [coreml] Error
>   Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=1 "Input image feature image does not
>   match model description" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Input image
>   feature image does not match model description,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x1c024cf90 {Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=1
>   "Image is not valid width 227, instead is 224"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Image is not valid width 227, instead
>   is 224}}}

The model you're using (I suspect it's SqueezeNet) expects input images of size 227x227, not 224x224 or any other size.

Comment: Thanks :) Strange ... didn't expect so simple error, because it is being done from Appcoda.com and supposed to be sized automatically ...
However just changed from:
if let buffer = image.buffer(with: CGSize(width:224, height:224))
to 
if let buffer = image.buffer(with: CGSize(width:227, height:227))
And it works now.